# p5.play won't run on repl.it

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am starting out using p5.play but I keep getting this error when I run any program (I use repl.it);

> p5 had problems creating the global function "Animation", possibly because your code is already using that name as a variable. You may want to rename your variable to something else.
> You just changed the value of "camera", which was a p5 function. This could cause problems later if you're not careful.

I can't use any funxtion in p5.play, loading images doesn't work (it creates an empty literal) and neither do sprites, how can I fix this?

```
const CANVASX = 800;
const CANVASY = 600;

let shipSpriteSheet;

function preload() {
  shipSpriteSheet = loadImage("images/shipsheet.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(CANVASX, CANVASY);
  pixelDensity(10)
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  image(shipSpriteSheet)
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this on the [official p5 editor?](https://editor.p5js.org)

Comment: The error doesn't seem to come from your code, are you sure you are not trying to instantiate p5.js or p5play twice? You should show us how you configured the import of these libraries. And to add to what Samathingamajig said: There is no reason this doesn't work in repl.it but works on other environments so this is most probably a configuration issue.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue statox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was instancing p5.js twice and not making use of [instance mode](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p) correctly.